# Как реализовать генерацию сочетаний без повторений?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Как лучше реализовать функцию `combine` с сигнатурой (JavaScript)

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // множество элементов
const k = 3; // размер сочетаний

const combinations = combine(array, k);
```

где `combinations` — все [**сочетания**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) из *array* по *k* (все возможные *k*-элементные **неупорядоченные** подмножества без повторений из *array*)?

---

Пример ожидаемого возвращённого значения:

```js
const combinations = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'd']
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O(n^k)** решение на JavaScript, на основе [скрипта](https://mgechev.github.io/javascript-algorithms/combinatorics_combinations.js.html) некого mgechev,

- где `n` — длина входного массива,
- `k` — размер комбинации.

```js
// TS: const combine = <T>(arr: T[], k: number, withRepetition = false) ): T[][] => {
const combine = (arr, k, withRepetition = false) => {
  const combinations = []
  const combination = Array(k)
   // TS: const internalCombine = (start: number, depth: number): void => {
  const internalCombine = (start, depth) => {
    if (depth === k) {
      combinations.push([...combination])
      return
    }
    for (let index = start; index < arr.length; index++) {
      combination[depth] = arr[index]
      internalCombine(index + (withRepetition ? 0 : 1), depth + 1)
    }
  }
  internalCombine(0, 0)
  return combinations
}

const array = [5, 3, 1, 0]
const k = 2

const combinations = combine(array, k)
console.log({ combinations: combinations.map(c => c.join()) })
```

---

**O(k * C(n, k))** решение на JavaScript,

- где `n` — длина входного массива,
- `k` — размер комбинации,
- а `C(n, k)` — количество сочетаний из `n` элементов по `k`.

  ```js
  // TS: const combinationsWithoutRepetitionCount = (n: number, k: number): number =>
  const combinationsWithoutRepetitionCount = (n, k) =>
    [...Array(k)].reduce((acc, _, i) => (acc * (n - i)) / (i + 1), 1)

  // TS: const combineWithoutRepetition = <T>(arr: T[], k: number): T[][] => {
  const combineWithoutRepetition = (arr, k) => {
    const n = arr.length
    const combinations = Array(combinationsWithoutRepetitionCount(arr.length, k)) // : T[][]

    const indexMask = [...Array(k)].map((_, i) => i)

    const endIndex = n - k
    for (let i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
      combinations[i] = indexMask.map((index) => arr[index])

      let left = k - 1
      while (left >= 0 && indexMask[left] === endIndex + left) left--
      if (left < 0) break

      indexMask[left]++
      for (let right = left + 1; right < k; right++) {
        indexMask[right] = indexMask[right - 1] + 1
      }
    }

    return combinations
  }

  const array = [5, 3, 1, 0]
  const k = 2

  const combinations = combineWithoutRepetition(array, k)
  console.log({ combinations: combinations.map(c => c.join()) })
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Алгоритм Twiddle за авторством **Phillip J. Chase**, из книги **Communications of the Association for Computing Machinery 13:6:368 (1970)**. Генерирует последовательность комбинаций при помощи замены одного элемента в предыдущей комбинации. Алгоритм не очень простой для понимания, привожу в конце ответа скриншот станицы книги. Ниже мой код генерирует комбинации в виде массива индексов, но их можно замаппить к элементам массива:

```js
function createCombinationsIterator(n, k) {
    let x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    let p = new Array(n + 2);
    let c = new Array(k);

    let init = function () {
        let i;
        p[0] = n + 1;
        for (i = 1; i != n - k + 1; i++) {
            p[i] = 0;
        }
        while (i != n + 1) {
            p[i] = i + k - n;
            i++;
        }
        p[n + 1] = -2;
        if (k == 0) {
            p[1] = 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            c[i] = i + n - k;
        }
    };

    let twiddle = function () {
        let i, j, m;
        j = 1;
        while (p[j] <= 0) {
            j++;
        }
        if (p[j - 1] == 0) {
            for (i = j - 1; i != 1; i--) {
                p[i] = -1;
            }
            p[j] = 0;
            x = z = 0;
            p[1] = 1;
            y = j - 1;
        } else {
            if (j > 1) {
                p[j - 1] = 0;
            }
            do {
                j++;
            } while (p[j] > 0);
            m = j - 1;
            i = j;
            while (p[i] == 0) {
                p[i++] = -1;
            }
            if (p[i] == -1) {
                p[i] = p[m];
                z = p[m] - 1;
                x = i - 1;
                y = m - 1;
                p[m] = -1;
            } else {
                if (i == p[0]) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    p[j] = p[i];
                    z = p[i] - 1;
                    p[i] = 0;
                    x = j - 1;
                    y = i - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    let first = true;
    init();

    return {
        hasNext: function () {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                let result = twiddle();
                if (result) {
                    c[z] = x;
                }
                return result;
            }
        },
        getCombination: function () {
            return c;
        }
    };
}

const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let iterator = createCombinationsIterator(4, 3);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    let combination = iterator.getCombination();
    console.log('indexes=' + combination.join(',') + ' mapped=' + combination.map(index => array[index]).join(','));
}
```

Так же этот алгоритм умеет генерировать комбинации в виде последовательности масок. Возможно в некоторых случаях маски будут полезнее. Пример ниже:

```js
function createCombinationMasksIterator(n, k) {
    let x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    let p = new Array(n + 2);
    let b = new Array(n);

    let initTwiddle = function () {
        let i;
        p[0] = n + 1;
        for (i = 1; i != n - k + 1; i++) {
            p[i] = 0;
        }
        while (i != n + 1) {
            p[i] = i + k - n;
            i++;
        }
        p[n + 1] = -2;
        if (k == 0) {
            p[1] = 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i != n - k; i++) {
            b[i] = 0;
        }
        while (i != n) {
            b[i++] = 1;
        }
    };

    let twiddle = function () {
        let i, j, m;
        j = 1;
        while (p[j] <= 0) {
            j++;
        }
        if (p[j - 1] == 0) {
            for (i = j - 1; i != 1; i--) {
                p[i] = -1;
            }
            p[j] = 0;
            x = z = 0;
            p[1] = 1;
            y = j - 1;
        } else {
            if (j > 1) {
                p[j - 1] = 0;
            }
            do {
                j++;
            } while (p[j] > 0);
            m = j - 1;
            i = j;
            while (p[i] == 0) {
                p[i++] = -1;
            }
            if (p[i] == -1) {
                p[i] = p[m];
                z = p[m] - 1;
                x = i - 1;
                y = m - 1;
                p[m] = -1;
            } else {
                if (i == p[0]) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    p[j] = p[i];
                    z = p[i] - 1;
                    p[i] = 0;
                    x = j - 1;
                    y = i - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    let first = true;
    initTwiddle();

    return {
        hasNext: function () {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                let result = twiddle();
                if (result) {
                    b[x] = 1;
                    b[y] = 0;
                }
                return result;
            }
        },
        getCombinationMask: function () {
            return b;
        }
    };
}

let iterator = createCombinationMasksIterator(4, 3);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    console.log(iterator.getCombinationMask().join(''));
}
```

[image: Описание алгоритма]

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; // множество элементов
const k = 4; // размер сочетаний

const combinations = combine2(array, k);
console.log("итого:", combinations);

function combine2(array, k) {
  const n = array.length - 1; // максимальный индекс массива элементов
  const m = k - 1; // максимальный индекс массива-маски сочетания
  const finds = []; // массив всех возможных осчетаний
  const mask = []; // маска сочетания
  let finish = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) mask.push(array[i]);
  while (!finish) {
    finish = true;
    const str = mask.join('');
    if (!finds.includes(str)) finds.push(str); // записываем сочетание в массив
    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      if (mask[m - i] != array[n - i]) {
        // проверяем, остались ли еще сочетания
        finish = false;
        let p = array.indexOf(mask[m - i]);
        mask[m - i] = array[++p]; // изменяем маску, начиная с последнего элемента
        for (let j = m - i + 1; j < k; j++) {
          mask[j] = array[++p];
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return finds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсивно через генератор:

```
function* generateCombs<T>(items: T[], combSize: number): Iterable<T[]> {
  if (combSize < 1) {
    yield [];
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= items.length - combSize; i++) {
    const restItems = items.slice(i + 1, items.length);

    for (const comb of generateCombs(restItems, combSize - 1)) {
      yield [items[i] as T, ...comb];
    }
  }
}
```