# Как на JS получить все возможные сочетания без повторов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Нашел аналогичный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205413/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9?ysclid=l5pe979jx4875753676), но не могу переделать ответ:

```
const combinations = combine2(array, k);
console.log("итого:", combinations);

function combine2(array, k) {
  const n = array.length - 1; // максимальный индекс массива элементов
  const m = k - 1; // максимальный индекс массива-маски сочетания
  const finds = []; // массив всех возможных осчетаний
  const mask = []; // маска сочетания
  let finish = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) mask.push(array[i]);
  while (!finish) {
    finish = true;
    const str = mask.join('');
    if (!finds.includes(str)) finds.push(str); // записываем сочетание в массив
   for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      if (mask[m - i] != array[n - i]) {
    // проверяем, остались ли еще сочетания
        finish = false;
        let p = array.indexOf(mask[m - i]);
        mask[m - i] = array[++p]; // изменяем маску, начиная с последнего элемента
        for (let j = m - i + 1; j < k; j++) {
          mask[j] = array[++p];
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return finds;
}
```

чтобы получался список списков int.

Например, дан список:

```
const array = [2, 3, 4, 5]; // множество элементов
const k = 2; // размер сочетаний
```

Нужно получить:

```
const combinations = combine2(array, k), как:
[[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в дубликате с повторами, а тут надо без них. Если был закрыт таким дубликтом, то предположу, что избавление от дубликатов имеется ввиду сделать на втором шаге. НО быть может есть алгоритм, который сразу выдаёт без повторов, потому не спешил бы я закрывать как минимум этим дубликатом

Comment: @EzioMercer, да предложенный дубликат не решил проблему. Проголосовал за перекрытие вопроса

Comment: @EzioMercer  может https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1293756/191482 ?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, там только пары насколько я понял

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Там только для пар, для 3-х и более не подходит по крайней мере в данном виде))

Comment: окей. пока открыл. но уверен что дублей тут ещё много, просто, как всегда, никто не пользуется поиском, а считает, что его проблема уникальна

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проблема не уникальна и как минимум обсуждалось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255037/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%a1), но  именно на JS реализацию не могу тут найти

Comment: @EzioMercer вот думаю оптимально было бы сделать общий вопрос для всех языков... Потому что если человек умеет в свой ЯП, то ему достаточно будет действительно только алгоритмов. А то так можно 1000 вопросов по всем ЯП задать но с одной и той же проблемой))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Можно, я вполне за. Тем более время от времени натыкался на такие вопросы, где просто на всех (почти) языках предлагали алгоритмы решения какой-то задачи. Так что если будешь организатором я поддержу :)

Comment: Погодите, а чем вас не устроил [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1352561/385375)? Делает ровно то что вам нужно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я что-то сразу не сообразил, но то что отметил сам автор там первый ответ - это ответ на вопрос. Первым аргументом вроде указывается кол-во элементов в массиве, так что можно всегда передавать `arr.length`, а вторым числом кол-во элементов в 1-ом сочетании. По крайней мере по моим простым тестам выдавал верные ответы

Comment: @EzioMercer не совсем просто понял этот ответ, потому и не брал его. В функцию там передается кол-во элементов, но не передается сам массив. Или я не вижу этого просто... как тогда по количеству понять какие значения комбинировать

Comment: @ChikChirik Там не массив передаётся, суть алгоритма в работе с индексами. Т.к. не важно массив чего поступит на вход, то суть влгоритма в выборке нужных элементов. Вот он и подготавливает нужные индексы заранее, а потом просто по индексам достаёт элементы из массива

Comment: @ChikChirik а этот ответ чем не устраивает? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205902/358745

Comment: @EzioMercer, спасибо наконец-то разобрался...